# ¿Cómo usar graphics.h en devcpp?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Ya copié los archivos **graphics.h** y **winbgim.h** en la ruta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include`.

Ya copié **libbgi.a** en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib`.

En Project Options >> Parameters >> Linker ya puse lo siguiente:

```
"../../../Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libbgi.a"
-libbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

El código que quiero probar es:

```
#include <graphics.h>

    int main( )
    {
        initwindow(400, 300, "First Sample");
        circle(100, 50, 40);
        while (!kbhit( ))
        {
            delay(200);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Al compilar me sale el siguiente error:

```
cannot find -libbgi
```

La versión de Devc++ es: **5.5.3**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DevCpp usa un compilador llamado MinGW, basado en los compiladores GNU para linux, en windows. De hecho, ese compilador se llama **MIN**imalistic **G**nu for **W**indows.
>   Para compilar en MinGW, si la librería lleva delante la palabra *lib*, tienes que modificar en DevCpp el *-l* asociado.

Para que puedas entenderlo con tu ejemplo, te lo aclaro viéndolo de esta forma:

- No necesitas copiar la librería a la carpeta libs, puedes usar -L **ruta_hasta_tu_directorio_de_trabajo** (con el espacio correspondiente): `-L "C:\Proyectos pruebas\fuente01\lib". De hecho, DevCpp te permite, entre sus opciones, incluir directorios de búsqueda de librerías, que te genera esta llamada de forma explícita.
- Tienes varias inclusiones a librerías que comienzan, todas, con `-l`. Centrémonos en `-lgdi32`. Trata de buscar qué archivos tienes en la carpeta de MinGW que contengan gdi32. Puedes hacerlo buscando `?gdi32.*` en la parte de búsqueda. ¡Sorpresa! El archivo se llama `libgdi32.a`. ¿Cómo lo *linkas*? poniendo `-lgdi32`. Prueba a hacer lo mismo con tu archivo, y ponle un `-lbgi`. Ahora te funciona, ¿verdad?

Una vez aprendas a usar DevCpp, te recomiendo que cambies a otro IDE, de cara al futuro. Ese entorno de programación utiliza un compilador de hace más de 15 años, porque hace 15 años ya estaba obsoleto. Te funcionará para hacer pruebas puntuales, pero si quieres adentrarte en realizar proyectos compatibles con GNU, te recomiendo que utilices Code::Blocks, Codelite, o cualquier otro IDE que te permita trabajar con compiladores más actualizados.

Comment: +1 por el último parráfo. Es importante resaltar que usar DevCpp en el pleno 2018 es un sinsentido. Si alguien quiere algo más "ligero" que VS, siempre existe Code::Blocks.